# iPhone, iPad wake screen command Issues/Bugs

Tags: appium

Is there an Appium command to wake iOS devices? I have a method which sometimes takes a while to run, and sometimes the device goes to sleep. I would like to wake the device so I can get a screenshot of the current state. Alternatively is there a bash command I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your iPhone settings:

Settings > General > Auto-Lock > Never